# How to plot grouped bar graph in core plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am implementing Bar charts using core plot. But from the last three days I am not implementing Grouped graphs in iOS. Grouped bar charts means multiple bar charts on X-axis.

```
- (void)generateLayout
{
    graph                               = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];// YOU CAN CHANGE THE THEME COLOR FROM HERE........
    self.hostedGraph                    = graph;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder   = NO;
    graph.paddingLeft                   = 10.0f;
    graph.paddingTop                    = 210.0f;       // ALTER THE SIZE OF GRAPH FROM TOP POSITION........
    graph.paddingRight                  = 80.0f;
    graph.paddingBottom                 = 90.0f;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *borderLineStyle    = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    borderLineStyle.lineColor               = [CPTColor blackColor];              // COLOR THE BOUNDARY OF THE GRAPH....
    borderLineStyle.lineWidth               = 2.0f;



    // GRAPH STYLE/SHAPE CHANGE IN X OR Y COORDINATE...........
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle     = borderLineStyle;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop          = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight        = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom       = 80.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft         = 70.0;


    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;
    plotSpace.globalXRange          = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt([dates count]+3)];


    plotSpace.delegate              = self;
    NSLog(@"set count=======%d",sets.count);//    6
    plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0)
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(200)];
    plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(-1)// IT WILL TAKE X TO AND FROM 0 OR OTHER COORDIANTE.....
                                                                   length:CPTDecimalFromInt(7)];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 2.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth            = 2.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor            = [[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;




    CPTXYAxis *x                    = axisSet.xAxis;

    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal   = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
    x.majorIntervalLength           = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);//majorIntervalLength defines the number of units between “big” ticks on the axis. In this case it’s set to show one every 10 units.
    x.minorTicksPerInterval         = 0;
    x.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.majorGridLineStyle            = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.axisConstraints               = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];



    //X labels
    int labelLocations = 0;
    NSMutableArray *customXLabels = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *day in dates)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:day textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation   = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:labelLocations] decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset         = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
        [customXLabels addObject:newLabel];
        labelLocations++;
        [newLabel release];
    }
    x.axisLabels                    = [NSSet setWithArray:customXLabels];

    CPTXYAxis *y            = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title                 = @"Calories burnt (kcal)";
    y.titleOffset           = 50.0f;                            //SET THE X-AXIS FOR THE LABEL(CALORIES BURNT)
    y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal=CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f);


    CPTXYAxis *y2 = (CPTXYAxis *)[[CPTXYAxis alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
    plotSpace2.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
    plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(60)];
    [graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
    y2.plotSpace = plotSpace2;
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(6.2);
    y2.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0f);
    y2.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;

    y2.title                       = @"Temperature";
    y2.titleLocation               = CPTDecimalFromInteger(30.0);    //THIS IS USED TO SET THE TITLE OF THE SECOND Y-AXIS..
    y2.titleTextStyle              =x.titleTextStyle;
    y2.titleOffset                 =-35.0f;

    graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects :x,y,y2,nil];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle   = [[[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init] autorelease];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth              = 1.0;
    barLineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor clearColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    whiteTextStyle.color                = [CPTColor whiteColor];



    for (NSString *set in [[sets allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)])
    {
        CPTBarPlot *plot        = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
        plot.lineStyle          = barLineStyle;
        CGColorRef color        = ((UIColor *)[sets objectForKey:set]).CGColor;
        plot.fill               = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:color]];
        if (firstPlot)
        {
            plot.barBasesVary   = NO;
            firstPlot           = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            plot.barBasesVary   = YES;
        }
        plot.barWidth           = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.5f);
        plot.barsAreHorizontal  = NO;
        plot.dataSource         = self;
        plot.identifier         = set;
        [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
    }


    CPTLegend *theLegend      = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
    theLegend.numberOfRows    = sets.count;
    theLegend.fill            = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.15]];
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = barLineStyle;
    theLegend.cornerRadius    = 10.0;
    theLegend.swatchSize      = CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0);
    whiteTextStyle.fontSize   = 18.0;
    theLegend.textStyle       = whiteTextStyle;
    theLegend.rowMargin       = 5.0;
    theLegend.paddingLeft     = 10.0;
    theLegend.paddingTop      = 10.0;
    theLegend.paddingRight    = 10.0;
    theLegend.paddingBottom   = 10.0;
    graph.legend              = theLegend;
    graph.legendAnchor        = CPTRectAnchorTopLeft;
    graph.legendDisplacement  = CGPointMake(80.0, -200.0);


}
```

Comment: Do you want to stack the plots one on top of another, or do you want the different plots grouped along the baseline, e.g., 123 123 123?

Comment: i want the different plots grouped along the baseline, just like e.g., 123 123 123?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `barOffset` property to shift the plots off the given bar location slightly. For example, with three plots, you might give the first plot an offset of -0.2, the second an offset of zero (the default), and the third an offset of +0.2, assuming your bars are one location unit apart.